# Details section doesn't display if 2 subreports are imported

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I use Crystal Reports to show the report data:

```
  Dim data As clsData = clsData.Instance
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim tblMyCompany As DataTable = data.GetDataTableFromQuery("select * from tblCompany where Id = (select CompId from tblCheckIn Where Id =" & CheckId & ")")
    tblMyCompany.TableName = "tblCompany"
    ds.Tables.Add(tblMyCompany)
    Dim tblCheckIn As DataTable = data.GetDataTableFromQuery("select * from tblCheckIn where id=" & CheckId)
    tblCheckIn.TableName = "tblCheckIn"
    ds.Tables.Add(tblCheckIn)

    Dim CheckInRoomQuery As DataTable = data.GetDataTableFromQuery("select * from CheckInRoomQuery where ChId=" & CheckId)
    CheckInRoomQuery.TableName = "CheckInRoomQuery"
    ds.Tables.Add(CheckInRoomQuery)
    Dim tblCheckInExtra As DataTable = data.GetDataTableFromQuery("select * from tblCheckInExtra where ChId=" & CheckId)
    tblCheckInExtra.TableName = "tblCheckInExtra"
    ds.Tables.Add(tblCheckInExtra)

    Dim ob As rptCheckOut = New rptCheckOut

    ob.SetDataSource(ds)

    ob.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(CheckInRoomQuery)
    'ob.Subreports(1).SetDataSource(tblCheckInExtra)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = ob
```

This code works well if I Insert only one subreport in detail section but fail when I insert second subreport in detail section. When I insert 2 subreports in the details section (detail section a, detail section b), then both section does not show data. I am sure that my query contains data. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why you need two sub-reports in one section?

You can solve your problem by two ways:

1. Merge the 2 subreports in one to display the data.
2. Use 2 GroupHeaders for the subreports. Group them based on a single entry from the table so they don't repeat.

Comment: ob.Subreports("rptCheckInRoom.rpt").SetDataSource(CheckInRoomQuery)
        ob.Subreports("rptCheckInExtra.rpt").SetDataSource(tblCheckInExtra)